# How to search between ranges in list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I want to find out the POS tags occurring between two ranges which are values of indices of NNP tags.

```
data = [[('User', 'NNP'),
  ('is', 'VBG'),
  ('not', 'RB'),
  ('able', 'JJ'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('order', 'NN'),
  ('products', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('iShopCatalog', 'NN'),
  ('Coala', 'NNP'),
  ('excluding', 'VBG'),
  ('articles', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('VWR', 'NNP')],
 [('Arfter', 'NNP'),
  ('transferring', 'VBG'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('articles', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('COALA', 'NNP'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('SRM', 'VB'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('Category', 'NNP'),
  ('S9901', 'NNP'),
  ('Dummy', 'NNP'),
  ('is', 'VBZ'),
  ('maintained', 'VBN')],
 [('Due', 'JJ'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('this', 'DT'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('user', 'NN'),
  ('is', 'VBZ'),
  ('not', 'RB'),
  ('able', 'JJ'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('order', 'NN'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('product', 'NN')],
 [('All', 'DT'),
  ('other', 'JJ'),
  ('users', 'NNS'),
  ('can', 'MD'),
  ('order', 'NN'),
  ('these', 'DT'),
  ('articles', 'NNS')],
 [('She', 'PRP'),
  ('can', 'MD'),
  ('order', 'NN'),
  ('other', 'JJ'),
  ('products', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('a', 'DT'),
  ('POETcatalog', 'NNP'),
  ('without', 'IN'),
  ('any', 'DT'),
  ('problems', 'NNS')],
 [('Furtheremore', 'IN'),
  ('she', 'PRP'),
  ('is', 'VBZ'),
  ('able', 'JJ'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('order', 'NN'),
  ('products', 'NNS'),
  ('from', 'IN'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('Vendor', 'NNP'),
  ('VWR', 'NNP'),
  ('through', 'IN'),
  ('COALA', 'NNP')],
 [('But', 'CC'),
  ('articles', 'NNP'),
  ('from', 'VBG'),
  ('all', 'RB'),
  ('other', 'JJ'),
  ('suppliers', 'NNS'),
  ('are', 'NNP'),
  ('not', 'VBG'),
  ('orderable', 'RB')],
 [('I', 'PRP'),
  ('already', 'RB'),
  ('spoke', 'VBD'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('anic', 'VB'),
  ('who', 'WP'),
  ('maintain', 'VBP'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('catalog', 'NN'),
  ('COALA', 'NNP'),
  ('and', 'CC'),
  ('they', 'PRP'),
  ('said', 'VBD'),
  ('that', 'IN'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('reason', 'NN'),
  ('should', 'MD'),
  ('be', 'VB'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('assignment', 'NN'),
  ('of', 'IN'),
  ('the', 'DT'),
  ('plant', 'NN')],
 [('User', 'NNP'),
  ('is', 'VBZ'),
  ('a', 'DT'),
  ('assinged', 'JJ'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('Universitaet', 'NNP'),
  ('Regensburg', 'NNP'),
  ('in', 'IN'),
  ('Scout', 'NNP'),
  ('but', 'CC'),
  ('in', 'IN'),
  ('P17', 'NNP'),
  ('table', 'NN'),
  ('YESRMCDMUSER01', 'NNP'),
  ('she', 'PRP'),
  ('is', 'VBZ'),
  ('assigned', 'VBN'),
  ('to', 'TO'),
  ('company', 'NN'),
  ('001500', 'CD'),
  ('Merck', 'NNP'),
  ('KGaA', 'NNP')],
 [('Please', 'NNP'),
  ('find', 'VB'),
  ('attached', 'JJ'),
  ('some', 'DT'),
  ('screenshots', 'NNS')]]
```

Following is my code.

```
list1 = []
list4 = []
for i in data:
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    for l,j in enumerate(i):
        if j[1] == 'NNP':
            list2.append(l)
            list3.append(j[0])
    list1.append(list2)
    list4.append(list3)
```

Output:

```
list1:

[[0, 9, 13],
 [0, 5, 9, 10, 11],
 [],
 [],
 [7],
 [9, 10, 12],
 [1, 6],
 [9],
 [0, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 20, 21],
 [0]]

list4

[['User', 'Coala', 'VWR'],
 ['Arfter', 'COALA', 'Category', 'S9901', 'Dummy'],
 [],
 [],
 ['POETcatalog'],
 ['Vendor', 'VWR', 'COALA'],
 ['articles', 'are'],
 ['COALA'],
 ['User',
  'Universitaet',
  'Regensburg',
  'Scout',
  'P17',
  'YESRMCDMUSER01',
  'Merck',
  'KGaA'],
 ['Please']]
```

From list1 and list4 i'm able to get the strings and indices of NNP. But i want to find out, in each list of lists if VB, RB, JJ tags are present between NNP tags using the index values of NNP tags.

For example, in first list of lists, how to write code to search between ranges (0-9) and (9-13) whether tags with VB, RB, JJ are present or not.

Comment: what is `NNP` – a tag? and how is `User` related to `NNP`?

Comment: i know that it's not related to question, but it's hard to reason about your code

Comment: NNP is a parts of speech tag. I modified some tags to write code. Not all tags are correct. My final expectation from these checks are to figure out a way to find product names and what is the intent about the product. I have a customer incidents dataset with incident description like Ex. Installation related to a product, repairs in a product, updates for a product, whether printer is not working. I don't find any NER taggers which can help me out to tag products.

Comment: what do you mean with POS tags?I can't find any `'POS'` strings in `data` so I believe you mean sth else

Comment: I mean NNP, VB, JJ etc are parts of speech (POS) tags for the strings which are in the 0th position of the tuple. For ex. In ('products', 'NNS') tuple 'products' is the string tagged with 'NNS' POS tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list comprehension, zip offset list1 to get indices of ranges
output range where the logic finds any match in sliced `data[0][j:k]` elements

```
[[j, k] for j, k in zip(list1[0][:], list1[0][1:])
        if any(t[1] in ['VB', 'RB', 'JJ'] for t in data[0][j:k])]

Out[107]: [[0, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

```
search_list = ['VB', 'RB', 'JJ']
for index, set in enumerate(list1):
    temp = set[::-1] # makes a copy of the list in reverse
    while len(temp) > 1:
        first = temp.pop() # removes the last item (first item of set) to control while loop
        second = temp[-1] # references next item (new last item)
        for i in range(first, second + 1): # search all indices between first and second
            if data[index][i][1] in search_list: # index the data by same index as current list1 item
                do_stuff()
```

Basically:

1. Use an enumerate in the outer for loop to keep a parallel index with the original data
2. Create a copy of each list in list1 to mess with. I made a reverse copy since I personally dislike using pop() with an index so if I want to pop the first item of a list over and over, I reverse the list.  You can make a regular copy and use list.pop(0) to remove and pass the first item
3. Pop the last (first) item from the list and reference the next.
4. Use the two items to create a range to index data and check for the mentioned items.

Comment: shouldn't it be `first = temp.pop()` on line 5? (with brackets)

Comment: Yeah.  Strangely enough, I could put the brackets on the pop, or on the use of first to create the range object